# Density of roots of polynomials with unit coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I want to prove that the set of $x \in (1/4,1/3)$ such that $x$ is the root of a polynomial $P$ with coefficients in $\{-1,0,1\}$, is dense. That is, $P(x) = 0$ where $P(t) = a_n t^n + a_{n-1} t^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$, and $a_n, a_{n-1}, \dots, a_0 \in \{-1,0,1\}$. I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure the problem is correctly stated as one can prove that if $0<x<1$ is a root of a $P(t)$ with coefficients $0, \pm 1$, we must have $x>\frac{1}{2}$ and moreover the positive roots of such are dense in $\frac{1}{2} \le x \le 2$

Let $0<x<1$ a root as above. Note that writing $P(t)=t^kP_1(t), P_1(0) \ne 0$ we get $P_1(x)=0$ too so wlog we can assume $a_0 \ne 0$ and then by taking $-P$ if needed we can assume $a_0=1$. But then:

$0=P(x)=1+\sum_{k=2}^na_kx^k \ge 1- (x+...x^n) > 1-(x+...x^n+...)=1-\frac{x}{1-x} \ge 0$ when $0<x \le \frac{1}{2}$ and that is a contradiction.

If $P(t)=a_n t^n+ a_{n-1}x^{n-1}...a_1t+1, a_n = \pm 1$ is as above and $P(x)=0$ then for $P^*(t)=t^n+a_1t^{n-1}+..a_{n-1}t+a_n$ we have $P^*(\frac{1}{x})=0$, so it is enough to prove the density statement above for $\frac{1}{2} \le x \le 1$

But $t^n-t-1$ has clearly a real root $1 <x_n \to 1$ when $n \to \infty$ as for any $a>1$ there is $n(a), a^n > a+1, n \ge n(a)$ and for $\frac{1}{2}$, $t^n++..+t-1=\frac{-t^n+2t-1}{-t+1}$ has a root $\frac{1}{2} < x_n \to \frac{1}{2}$

So one needs to prove the result for $\frac{1}{2} < x <1$ and then noticing that $x^{n+1}+...=\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x} >x^n$ we can get a sequence of roots as needed by first taking the first $n_1$ high enough so $x^{n_1}+...x-1 >0$ so there is a root sligthly less than $x$ for $t^{n_1}+...t-1$.

Since $x^{n_1-1}+..x-1 <0$, by the observation above we can add enough terms $-x^{n_1+1}+..-x^{n_1+k}$ with $-x^{n_1+1}+..-x^{n_1+k}+x^{n_1}<0$ hence the polynomial $-t^{n_1+1}+..-t^{n_1+k}+t^{n_1}+t^{n_1-1}+..t-1$ has a root slightly bigger than $x$ and then with $n_2=n_1+k$ the first such, add enough positive terms from $n_2+1$ on to get a root smaller than $x$ and so on, and it is clear that those roots will converge to $x$